# Is this an appropriate use of "vice versa"?

Tags: word-usage

> Favoring math has taught me that what you're most passionate about is not always what you're the best at, and vice versa.

I'm afraid the part that the "vice versa" refers to is too long, which would make the meaning of the sentence unclear. Should I write it out instead? The sentence would then be:

> Favoring math has taught me that what you're most passionate about is not always what you're best at, and what you're best at is not always what you're the most passionate about.

Comment: A bit lengthy as the sentence may be, there isn't really that much information to cause any noticeable confusion. I'd go with the first alternative.

Comment: For me the goal is clarity.  Spelling it out - your second option - is easier to follow.  I prefer it (I'm, er, easily confused...!)

Comment: It seems reasonably clear to me.  The rewrite is too long to be a single sentence and still be comprehended without extra effort.  (Though there is probably some minor rewording that would make the original sentence flow better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a point with the first sentence, but I think the best solution does not lie in spelling it out. I think the use of "is" in the sense of "implies" (logically speaking) makes for the need to use "vice versa", which makes the sentence unnecessarily long to say what you mean. I include a suggestion below. Note that I flipped the order so that in the first use of "what" it's immediately clear that we're talking about an activity rather than any number of non-activity things.

"Favoring math has taught me that what you're best at and what you're most passionate about can differ."

Answer (score 0):

Your *vice versa* works fine for me.  The beginning part isn't so clear, though.  "Favoring"?  That part is the cryptic part, for my ear.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. Boiled down to its essentials, the sentence is "Passionate is not always best," and vice versa. (Best is not always passionate.)

The sentence is not really "too long."